# Tabs with several Activities per tab

Tags: android, tabs, activitygroup

I have developed this application which uses an `ActivityGroup` to switch between `Activity`s in a tab. I have downloaded the newest AdMob SDK, forcing me to use a `targetSdkVersion` of 13 instead of 8. Because of that, I get the warning that `ActivityGroup` is deprecated.

What is the new way of switching between `Activity`s in a single tab? I'd rather keep my `minSdkVersion` at 8. And are there any examples of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the new way of switching between Activitys in a single tab?

There is no "new way of switching between Activitys in a single tab". The closest thing to a "new way" is to not use activities-in-tabs, but to use fragments-in-tabs, or tabs in the action bar (that alter the UI, such as by changing fragments).

The [JavaDocs for `TabActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html) show how to implement fragments-in-tabs.

Comment: 95% of my users use Android 2.x, so I guess `Fragment`s are not really an option, since they are only implemented from API level 11? Like I said, I only changed the build target to 13 because otherwise the Admob SDK wouldn't work, so should I just ignore the deprecated warning and keep it like I have it now?

Comment: @Niek: The Android Support package gives you fragments that work back to Android 1.6. "so should I just ignore the deprecated warning and keep it like I have it now?" -- you are welcome to do so if you choose. How well this will work in the long term is anyone's guess.